# Swift: print() command not printing to console in Xcode 7.3.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm currently in the process of making my first Swift project for iOs on Xcode. My current issue is that it seems that all print() commands I have in my code do not actually print text into my console window. I've looked this issue up in various places but cannot seem to find anyone else with the same problem, so I'm assuming I have some sort of syntax error or my understanding of swift/xcode is simply wrong. Here is the block of code I have:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Configure the view.
    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setValue("white",forKey: "petColor")
    let bugcheck = defaults.stringForKey("petColor")
    print(bugcheck)
    print("hello yes this works")

    // Create and configure the scene.
    scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    // Present the scene.
    skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
```

This is in the GameViewController.swift file that is made by default upon creation of a new project. The lines:

```
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setValue("white",forKey: "petColor")
    let bugcheck = defaults.stringForKey("petColor")
    print(bugcheck)
    print("hello yes this works")
```

Is the part I am trying to get to work. I want to know that defaults are being correctly saved/loaded. When I run the app in simulator the view loads, and the scene is presented (I have some images pop up on screen), so I know that the code is atleast being run. However, nothing shows up on the console. What gives? Sorry if this question has been asked before but like I said I could not find a resource. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you sure you have the view open that shows the printed statements?

Comment: Add a breakpoint to make sure you are in fact reaching the line of code that prints.

Comment: Breakpoints did indeed help me figure out the issue, thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set/add a breakpoint because sometimes methods in other files for example with recursive blocks or segues could be preempting the call of the print line. If you see your print statement after you have set a break point then you know something which is getting called is preempting the call of the print statement.

[Adding, Disabling, and Deleting Breakpoints](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/chapters/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints.html)

Also, this may sound obvious so don't shoot me, but many people mistakenly disable the console view. **shift+command+C** shows the console
view.

In addition, you can also use `nslog` to print to device logs to see if it makes a difference. `nslog` adds time-stamps etc. `NSLog("Can anyone hear me?")` Then go to Xcode -> Window -> Devices and check the device logs. You can also check OS X Console Application for the same logs.

Comment: Yes, once I started messing with breakpoints I managed to get it to work. Thanks so much! I'm a little confused as to how exactly breakpoints fixed the issue, but I'm grateful nevertheless. Thanks again!

Comment: Breakpoints simply allow you to essentially stop the program at whatever point you set the breakpoint at. They aren't fixing anything really. If you saw your print statement that just means you stopped the program at a breakpoint where the print statement had a chance to print before another function or method preempted the print statement. So then you now have to find out what code is preempting your print line. If you're in fact interested in finding out.

Comment: OMG. Yes. The Console was hidden. Had the Variable view open but not the Console. Ugh. Thank you. Moving on.

Answer (score 1):

That issue happened recently to me.

The problem was that I had connected my iPad as extended display using Duet app. Currently this connection is performed via Air Play and for some weird reason, logs in Xcode disappears.

Hope this help to someone else.